# PowerShell regex return 8 consecutive digits only from string

Tags: powershell, regex

I'm having trouble getting a string to return using [replace()](https://ss64.com/ps/replace.html) where I need to get the numerical digits but only from the digits that are in an 8 character side by side group consecutively.

Some of these strings will have other numbers within them but these numbers will not ever be in an 8 group collection so I'd like to omit those and return only the digits that are in the 8 digit group.

[image]

### Clarification

These strings are really file names but if I can get some help with this simple example for the expected result, I can easily incorporate into the other **PowerShell** logic of the scripted process.

- I prefer to not use the `YYYY` from current year, `$YYYY = (get-date).year` or anything like that and then look for other digits so the file name itself dictates action and not year regardless
- I tried various methods and even got some to return `TRUE` using  IN think `"[^0-9]{8}.*$` or something like that but nothing to easily return the actual 8 digits themselves.

---

### Example Data Strings

```
error_PP3_XXX_PSI_20180109PM.err
error_PP3_XXX_PSI_20180110AM.err
error_PP3_XXX_PSI_20180111PM.err
error_PP3_XXX_PSI_20180115PM.err
error_PP3_XXX_Temp_20180110AM.err
error_YYY_20180109AM.err
error_YYY_20180109PM.err
```

---

### PowerShell

- **Correct result**

  *This is a working example where only the 8 consecutive digits are in the string*

  > ```
  > "error_YYY_20180109PM.err" -replace "[^0-9]" , ""
  > ```
  >
  > **Result**
  >
  > ```
  > 20180109
  > ```
- **Incorrect result**

  *This is a non-working example where there are additional numerical characters in the string than just the 8 consecutive digits*

  > ```
  > "error_PP3_XXX_PSI_20180115PM.err" -replace "[^0-9]" , ""
  > ```
  >
  > **Result**
  >
  > ```
  > 320180115
  > ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work
`if ("error_PP3_XXX_PSI_20180109PM.err" -match "([0-9]{8})"){$matches[1]} else {""}`

Assumes that you do not have more than one group of 8 digits. 
Please also note that $matches stays set even if following command does not match. So you may want to clear it manually using `clear-variable matches` (or using shorter alias `clv matches`)

Comment: This works well for my particular need where there will always only be one group of 8 digits but changing the `([0-9]{<#>})` where `<#>` can be any number other than just 8 should make this a feasible solution where applicable for other group digit numbers as well. Just FYI... The final script uses something like `Get-Childitem -Path $sourceFolder\error_*.err -Name | ForEach-Object { if ("$_" -match "([0-9]{8})"){$x=$matches[1]} else {$x=""} }` for that portion of the logic.

Comment: One more thing wmz, I do not seem to be affected by the `$matches` you talked about so perhaps I was doing something differently or just don't see it or perhaps that won't apply for the way the logic flows with the `ForEach-Object` I used the method with but here's a screen shot of that portion of the logic entirely in case you want to see all those parts involved: https://i.imgur.com/ICRwfgu.png.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT There is a guard in the snippet I posted, it will use matches only if there is a match, or else it returns empty string. So my note about manually clearing it was rather targeted at future visitors, more likely to cherry pick parts of it.