# Copy files with specific names into different folders

Tags: powershell, file-transfer, copy-paste

I need to copy many files into different folders.
My files look like this:

aaa_280_, aaa_281_, aaa_282_

They are all in one source folder.
The destination folders look like this:

xy_280, xy_281, ...

This code works for on copy process in powershell :

```
copy-item "Source\*" "destination\xy_280" -Filter "aaa_280*
```

Is there a way I can loop over all files, with an increasing value "+1" so that the destiantion and filter both increase after each successful copy? Thanks

Comment: You are only getting files. You have to create new locations first using the ```New-Item``` cmdlet. See the examples on your system. ```Get-Help -Name New-Item -Examples```. View the full details using  ```Get-Help -Name New-Item -Examples``` or the PowerShell docs on the PS Micorosft site, or just search for the many examples all over the web. This is a very simple task using loops, and using the file basename in a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This now works, with warnings:

```
> Clear-Host
>> Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\source' -Filter 'abc_*' |
>> FOrEach-Object {
>>     New-Item -Path 'D:\destination' -ItemType Directory -Name $PSItem.BaseName.Substring(8,3)
>>     Copy-Item -Path $PSItem.FullName -Destination "D:\destiantion\$($PSItem.BaseName.Substring(8,3))"
>> }
```

With the substring I was able to isoalte and group all files that need to go into the same folder. The error messages are coming, I believe, because the destination folders already exsist after a first file is copied there.

Thx again.

Comment: No worries. My reply was to get you started and lead you to whatever you required. Glad you could understand and refactor for your use case, and yeppers, if X or Y exists that you'd have to take that under consideration. Lastly, you could have also just used a ```if/then``` or ```try/catch``` statement to deal with the existence of any item. You could suppress errors, if you know your stuff is valid as well, using the ```ErrorAction``` setting.

Comment: See detail in the help file or this [MS blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/hey-scripting-guy-how-can-i-use-the-erroraction-preference-parameter/#:~:text=One%20of%20the%20cool%20things%20you%20can%20do,or%20each%20line%20of%20code%20in%20your%20script.)

Answer (score 2):

As per my comment.

```
Clear-Host
Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\Temp' -Filter 'abc*' | 
FOrEach-Object {
    New-Item -Path 'D:\Temp' -ItemType Directory -Name $PSItem.BaseName -WhatIf
    Copy-Item -Path $PSItem.FullName -Destination "D:\Temp\$($PSItem.BaseName)" -WhatIf
}
# Results
<#
What if: Performing the operation "Create Directory" on target "Destination: D:\Temp\abc - Copy - Copy".
What if: Performing the operation "Copy File" on target "Item: D:\Temp\abc - Copy - Copy.bat Destination: D:\Temp\abc - Copy - Copy".
What if: Performing the operation "Create Directory" on target "Destination: D:\Temp\abc - Copy".
What if: Performing the operation "Copy File" on target "Item: D:\Temp\abc - Copy.bat Destination: D:\Temp\abc - Copy".
What if: Performing the operation "Create Directory" on target "Destination: D:\Temp\abc".
What if: Performing the operation "Copy File" on target "Item: D:\Temp\abc.bat Destination: D:\Temp\abc".
What if: Performing the operation "Create Directory" on target "Destination: D:\Temp\ABC_123".
What if: Performing the operation "Copy File" on target "Item: D:\Temp\ABC_123.xls Destination: D:\Temp\ABC_123".
#>
```

Just remove the `-WhatIf` for it to do stuff.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Now I get a single Folder for every single file. What I want is all files that are named "aaa_280_X" to go in a the "280" folder. All files "aaa_281_X" to go into the folder "*281". So the solution needs some adjustments I believe?

Comment: In case this helps either of you, I asked a question here: https://superuser.com/questions/1285892/powershell-regex-return-8-consecutive-digits-only-from-string doing something similar and per this screen shot of the logic I put in a comment, I used this sort of logic to do this: https://i.imgur.com/ICRwfgu.png

Comment: @Vomit IT - Chunky Mess Style, thx, but I've never found myself in any role in my career where this sort of thing has ever been needed. So, always good to have more info though for those who may need it.

Comment: All good, I've had to find a lot of brute force hack type things like this in my roles at time based on things not being able to be changed at higher levels to fix the real problem (e.g. program can't be rewritten to write to `yyyymmdd` folder, etc.). In any event, none of us don't know what we don't know, so we're really all just alike at the end of the day. I'm so glad I met PowerShell though and made that transition. Learning everyday myself for my life-long learning journey and commitment.  Keep giving back postanote, I see you, and thank you!

Comment: Ditto regarding all you stated here. Giving back is what makes all this worth it.  We learn as much from it as we give to others, and that's the hotness.